# Is it OK to have a namespace name which exists at two points in the tree?

Tags: c#, .net

Is this OK:

```
namespace Simple.OData
{
    // Common OData functionality
}

namespace Simple.Data.OData
{
    // The Simple.Data adapter for OData
}
```

It feels like it might be wrong, but I'm not sure.

Comment: [This other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918894/namespace-naming-conventions/918913#918913) give you a link with namaspaces naming guidelines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's certainly valid - consider `System.Xml.Linq` and `System.Linq`. I can't immediately foresee any problems... but that's not to say it's *necessarily* a good idea.

Personally I prefer `Simple.Data.OData` over `Simple.OData.Data`, as I suspect this is primarily aimed at people who are using `Simple.Data`, but happen to be using OData - not people who are *focused* on `OData`. Again, this is like LINQ: `System.Xml.Linq` is an XML API which plays will with LINQ; it's not a LINQ "provider" as such.

Basically it's the same sort of problem as "I have a converter to convert from type A to type B; do I put it near type A or type B?" - but with namespaces. My experience is that usually more head-scratching goes into thinking of the best thing to do than the problems that would be caused by taking either approach...

Comment: Just wondering why originally was not considered "System.Linq.Xml" instead of "System.Xml.Linq", for me it looks more clear

Comment: It probably exists in the `System.Xml` assembly, rather than the `System.Linq` one?

Comment: @sllev: I was just adding a comment to that effect - fundamentally it's an XML API. You use it when you want to work with XML data - and it happens to work well with LINQ.

Comment: @Kieren: Actually it has its own assembly anyway (System.Xml.Linq)

Comment: I was hoping for an example of this in the BCL, and had forgotten System.Xml.Linq. Precedent found! Ta.

Answer (score 5):

More correct would be, `namespace Simple.OData.Data`.

This is because the `Data` namespace should be grouped with the other classes relating to `OData`.

If you're thinking along with lines of `System.Data`, `System.Data.SqlClient` then it's pretty much because they are a part of the `System.Data.dll` assembly, and are an integrated part of it.  My own implementation of the `IDbCommand` etc classes live in `MyNamespace.SubNamespace.AdoWrapper` namespace, if that gives you some context.

In your case, `Simple.Data` presumably doesn't exist or have much in it, unlike `System.Data` ..

Comment: +1 but would have sounded cooler as "more correct namespace Simple.OData.Data would be, young Padawan" :p

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is, if it's semantically correct. Look at how many framework namespaces end in `.Design`, for example!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, but there are some drawbacks.

The namespace is part of the type name.
That is, a type named `C` inside namespace `A.B`, is actualy named `A.B.C`.

When you use the `using` statement, then you are just using a kind of **shortcut**.

*Drawbacks:*

I have noticed that sometimes Visual Studio may become little confused, specialy when using namespaces such as `System`, and others that exist in the .Net framework... in such a way that you must enter the full name of the type.

Answer (score 0):

It might be confusing to some people, but it should not cause any problems.
You'll probably need to preprend the namespace though if you type this:

```
using Simple.Odata;
using Simple.Data.Odata;
```

Otherwise the compile won't recognise it.
There's probably a better structure possible for the thing you're trying to create, but to anwser your question : yes it is ok to do it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

The last part should be dependant on previous part(s) of the namespace. Your adapter has a dependancy with Simple.OData but also with Simple.Data. But since Simple.OData is less generic I'd prefer something like:

```
using Simple.Data    

namespace Simple.OData.Adapters
{
    // The Simple.Data adapter for OData   
}
```