# How to choose a good namespace name? [Linguistically]

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions

English in not my native language, therefore it is a little more difficult to pick a good name for a namespace. Are there any best practices, conventions or rules I should adhere to?

One example to make you see my problem a bit better:

*We have a set of classes that have to do with the way a company is organized (we can create organizational charts with it). Currently the namespace is `CFW.CoreSystem.Organizational`. Is this a good name?*

Comments are most welcome!

<sub>(There are many questions about good **class** names, but this question is about **namespaces**!)</sub>

**Edit**
What is **linguistically** the best way to name a namespace? (`CFW.CoreSystem.Configuration` is better than `CFW.CoreSystem.Configurables`).

Comment: you will get better answers at [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: There is a Similar question in SO too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918894/namespace-naming-conventions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Follow Microsoft guidelines:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026.aspx

> Company.(Product|Technology)[.Feature][.Subnamespace]

Comment: All good and well.. but it doesn't say anything about the way a Subnamespace is named. 'Configuration' is a better namespace than 'Configurable'. Any ideas about linguistics?

Comment: Yeah, still you can see other guidelines [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use namespaces to group your classes in a logical way. If your classes are al about organizational stuff, than yes, this is a good namespace. BUT, I think your classes should be grouped more to the shared purpose they have. So, if you have a bunch of controllers...ad them to the CFW.CoreSystem.Controllers namespace for example.

Answer (score 0):

In our company every namespace starts with the company name, after that the program, so they look like:

```
Company.Program.BL.Something;
```

Answer (score 0):

MSDN article - [.Net Framework Naming Pattern and Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

> A consistent naming pattern is one of the most important elements of
>   predictability and discoverability in a managed class library.
>   Widespread use and understanding of these naming guidelines should
>   eliminate many of the most common user questions. This topic provides
>   naming guidelines for the .NET Framework types. For each type, you
>   should also take note of some general rules with respect to
>   capitalization styles, case sensitivity and word choice.