# Namespace naming convention when [CompanyName] starts with a lower case "i"

Tags: visual-studio, namespaces, resharper, naming, stylecop

My company name starts with a lower case "i".  For example: iWare (this is not the real company name, but it demonstrates the purposes).

Because of this I find that I am constantly having to fight StyleCop and Resharper due to the namespace naming rules / conventions.

Does anyone have any ideas how should I be naming my namespaces (and sometimes classes).

EG.

```
namespace iWare.Product.X
{
    ...
}
```

As you can imagine, most of the tools shown above do not like this.  Are there any suggestions as to what an alternative should be? I have tried suppressing the error using the following:

```
[SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.NamingRules", "SA1300:ElementMustBeginWithUpperCaseLetter", Justification = "Reviewed. Suppression is OK here.")]
namespace iWare.Product.X
{
    ...
}
```

But, this results in the following error: A namespace declaration cannot have modifiers or attributes

Any ideas?

Comment: Personally I would just call it Iware. Does it matter that the case is different between the company name and the code? Is there any likelyhood of a clash of code between yours and the real Iware?

Comment: Woody, thanks for this. The issue is further worsened when i tell you that the name of the company is actually an acronym.  So it's actually iWARE.  This would mean that the namespace using your method would be: IWARE.  I think it looks a little bit too much like an interface and the block caps looks pretty bad too. IMO.

Comment: I would still go for Iware, the naming convention on the code is just that, a convention. It is one less thing to look for in the error list!

Comment: Lets look at MS namespaces, they have just Microsoft.CSharp library and i think thats nothing bad to follow .net founder. The answer is IWare

Comment: This question belongs better  at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like you're using iWare, or your company name, as your root namespace.

On my projects, I generally specify my root namespace in/using the property window of MyProject, or MenuItem 'Project' > 'Properties' > 'Application' - 'root namespace' textbox on right.

Thus, I don't specify it in my coding at all, unless I'm referencing it from another component/project as an import.

Comment: That makes sense.  In my case, iWARE is also the product name. I'm not totally clear how or if that changes things, but I can see how your solution is a good one.

Answer (score 5):

[Brett's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11623425/473305) addresses the issue with tools, but to answer the question in the title (what namespace-naming convention should be used when a company's name begins with a lowercase letter):

[This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026.aspx), linked to from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4623870/473305), states,

> If your brand employs nontraditional casing, you should follow the casing defined by your brand, even if it deviates from normal namespace casing.

So according to Microsoft the correct namespace name in your example would in fact be `iWare.Product.X`, with a lowercase "i".