# How to use the string Constructor in typescript 2

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

`StringConstructor` is working in Typescript 1.8:

```
interface StringConstructor {
    trim(msg: string): string;
}
String.trim = function (msg: string) {
                if (msg)
                    return msg.trim();
                return msg;
            }
 String.trim("Url)
```

but not working in Typescript 2 and I get the error:

> Property 'trim' does not exist on type 'StringConstructor'.

Comment: This code, when copied to playground and then runs in the console, works well.

Comment: Property 'trim' is defined above on type 'String'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 module String {
  export function trim(msg: string): string {
    if (msg)
      return msg.trim();
    return msg;
  }
}
String.trim("Url")
```

(Note that you missed the string closing quotation mark)

Explanation In short:
TypeScript does something called declaration merging, which is explained in [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).

For more info see Jeffery's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17845907/7126139)

Comment: This seems like an overkill. Why take this approach when there's a simpler one like the one the OP is trying?

Comment: I couldn't make this approach work with my Typescript 2 compiler. Would love to see working examples of this approach :)
For example - [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18853267/7126139)  supposed to be a working example, yet did not pass my compiler.

Comment: The code in the answer you linked to work great in playground, just like the code the OP posted.

Comment: I've saw that before. I'm not sure which typescript compiler/version playground uses. I've checked it locally using ver 2.0.6 & 2.0.8 and got the same errors as @Hossein.

In other words, although you're right, I don't see how it help solving the problem.

Comment: Have you tried putting it in `declare global { ... }`?

Comment: No, Can you add an example of it?

Comment: `declare global { interface StringConstructor { ... } }` and then `String.trim = ...`.  There's not much documentation on that, but you can see a bit in [Global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation).

Comment: Great, I'll look into it. Thanx!