# Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype .. problem in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In some old QA, I found a couple of code such as

[how to extend Array in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658190/how-to-extend-arrayt-in-typescript)

[Extend native JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000645/extend-native-javascript-array)

I am investigating how it behaves under TypeScript.

```
interface Array<T> {
  "foo": Function;
  ["foo"]: Function;
}

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "foo", {
  value: function <T>(this, R: T) {
    return (console.log(R));
  }
});

[].foo("test");   // test
[]["foo"]("test");  //test
```

Basically, the code works,
[The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mAVYvW)

However, for some reason, in VSCode, TypeScript produces errors

[image]

[image]

At least I tried to type the Array property.

`"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true` in tsconfig.json surely suppresses these errors, but I want to know how to make it work without this flag.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Please share any relevant code by editing your Question - [instead of a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Fewer people are likely to reproduce your issue without having your code in a copyable form.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing. Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](//tsplay.dev/mAVYvW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. Right now there are no errors in the TS Playground, so your issue isn't clear. I suspect it has to do with modules and you will need to do some [global augmentation](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) to deal with it, but without a [mre] it's just speculation.

Comment: Do you use TypeScript v4.4.4 like in the playground?

Comment: @tjheslin1 I shared the full relevant copyable code, and as you see the code in the screenshot is identical. The purpose is to address the actual errors. Thanks.

Comment: @GuerricP Yes, the Both v4.4.3 and 4.4.4 have the same result, and thanks for you guys to let me know it works ok in the playground, so there must be some glitch somewhere.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your playground link, and I added in my Question. I feel somewhat better it works without problem there. I don't know why my VScode environment produces the errors.

Comment: I think at this point, assuming you want to figure this out, your job is now to reproduce the issue yourself in a different environment, such as the TS Playground.  Copy more of your code into the other IDE and see what happens (hint: do you have any code with `export` in it?) and work on it until you get a [mre]. Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz I really appreciate your inspiration. Actually, thanks to your playground link, I tried more possibilities, and finally, it turns out `interface Arrays(T)` line must be the top level of the code without `{....}`  Thanks a LOT!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your inspirations especially for @jcalz.

Here's the thing...

[image]

[image]

```
interface Array<T> {
  "foo": Function;
  ["foo"]: Function;
}
```

must be the top level of the code of TypeScript, that I really did not know.

Thank you guys anyway!!