# How to name namespaces with composed names?

Tags: c#, namespaces

Let's say I own a domain called `www.john-doe.com`. How would I write an appropriate namespace in C#?

Is it `Com.John_Doe.<product-name>` ?

All I read about C# namespace convetions is that it should use PascalCase. But what about the minus sign? Is it appropriate to write an underscore for it?

Comment: By formatting it that way, it looks as though you are creating an android application space.  Namespaces ought to be relevant to the organization of your code and can be whatever is meaningful.

Comment: Just pick a convention you like and stick with it

Comment: namespaces in C# have nothing to do with domains or anything like that. That looks like a (very awkward) java convention, which makes no sense whatsoever. if your product is called `My-Product` then you should do `MyProduct.Data` for the data layer, `MyProduct.Model` for the model, `MyProduct.UI` for the UI and so forth. [forget java](http://whyjavasucks.com/).

Comment: You might poke around a popular open source C# project and see how they set up their namespaces: https://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: [Namespace conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229026.aspx) and [capitalization conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx) which tell you not to use underscores (the same would go for hyphens), FYI.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/893ke618(v=vs.71).aspx  and another Stack Overflow question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918894/namespace-naming-conventions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to .NET [namespace conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229026.aspx), you should use pascal casing in namespaces (unless that goes against non-standard casing your company/brand/product uses). And according to [capitalization conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), pascal casing should not include underscores. [General naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) also tell you to not use hyphen (which will actually produce compiler errors in C# anyway).

Unless `Com` is intended to be replaced with your company name (from the context, "John Doe" sounds like the company) You should just go with:

```
JohnDoe.<ProductName>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! But with `JohnDoe.<ProductName>` one comes in conflict with `www.johndoe.com` using the same namespace? :-(

Comment: I suppose if you own both website and have projects for both, you'll have an unfortunate namespace collision. Perhaps that would justify using an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is personal preference. E.g. my preference is JohnDoe.