# In C#, what are the namespace naming conventions for individuals?

Tags: c#, namespaces, naming-conventions, naming

I am try to find a namespace naming-convention for code I release as an individual outside of a company environment.

The [Microsoft guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/893ke618%28vs.71%29.aspx) only help for code written by companies.

> The general rule for naming namespaces is to use the company name followed by the technology name and optionally the feature and design
>   as follows.
>
> ```
> CompanyName.TechnologyName[.Feature][.Design]
> ```

But what should I do as an individual with no company?

In Java I would use the address of my personal website, but in C# url-like namespaces do not seem to be favoured.

---

This is a subtly different question to [namespace naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918894/namespace-naming-conventions), since it is about naming conventions for individuals, not companies.

Comment: so use your internet handle, your last name, or don't include the first "section" it at all. Seems like you have less than a handful of options.

Comment: Typically, individuals or open source libraries omit the `CompanyName` part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO,If you release it as individual I think better name it like your project/program name, let's imagine that you writing a library with code name "SuperLib" : `SuperLib.SuperFeature.SuperDesign`.

Answer (score 2):

This is totally subjective, but the format I use is:

```
<SolutionName>.<ProjectName>.<FolderName>.<SubfolderName>.<SubSubFolderName>.<etc>
```

For me, at least I find that my namespacing closely follows my folder structure.

Here are a few examples:

```
namespace Project.Models.DTO

namespace Project.Domain.Services.Implementations

namespace Project.Controllers
```

Comment: `namespace Project.Models.DTO` should be `namespace Project.Models.Dto` actually since `Dto` is an acronym