# c# namespace naming conventions

Tags: c#, namespaces, naming-conventions

Another developer at my company created a new class library using the following namespace:

MyCompany.Repositories.Users

Based on my experience over the years I would expect this namespace to be named as:

MyCompany.Repository.User

Which style do you normally use for your namespaces?  I was thinking my style was somewhat standard.  It looks cleaner to me. Can you provide any authoritative urls which recommend namespace naming conventions?

Comment: You could look at this [Namespace naming convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This is definitely an opinion based question

Comment: I would suggest looking to the .NET class namespaces. To keep it consistent.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026(v=vs.110).aspx

"CONSIDER using plural namespace names where appropriate."

I guess plural seems to be the way to go or at least an acceptable way to go

Comment: @jeroen - unfortunately I don't think there's a similar type of namespace in the .net class libs?

Comment: @user6604655 I meant by using singular or plural.

Comment: .NETCoreApp dll has the following namespace:
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions

so it looks like the singular/plural rule is flexible and possibly leans towards plural

Comment: Could you give some examples of classes that reside within the MyCompany.Repositories.Users namespace?

Comment: @rav - to be practical, let's refer to this namespace as MyCompany.Repositories which has a UserRepository class

Comment: Thanks! I will post my answer below.

Comment: This is also addressed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918894/namespace-naming-conventions where it has a more elaborate answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Interesting question.  I've never seen any advice beyond "use plurals where appropriate" for C#.

Let's assume that the namespace is `MyCompany.Repositories`

Borrowing from [a similar question posed in the Java world](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75919/should-package-names-be-singular-or-plural) I would suggest that plural is valid. The components that live within the *Repositories* namespace will be homogeneous in the sense that they are all repositories (`UserRepository`, `StudentRepository`, `LocationRepository`, etc).

Conversely, a namespace like `MyCompany.ReportingEngine` would be valid as a singularly-named namespace, as this namespace may contain heterogeneous classes that do very different things (IE a query generator class, a report model, a field model, a filtering model). `MyCompany.ReportingEngines` would suggest that this namespace contains different types of classes that *are* reporting engines.